# A silly question regarding a badly written exercise for probability equations.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am doing some exercises and this [silly question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn2fp.png) is bothering me even though I am familiar with probability theory and Bayes law but this question is written in a rather peculiar manner I have no idea regarding what steps I should take first and how to finalise the equations as I have multiple variables to work into a single formula. Do I have to use some sort of a formula to add/subtract variables before I apply them in a probability equation?

Comment: As every customer buys exactly one coffee, the number of coffees sold is the number of customers.  Thus Aroma, say, had $150$ customers.  We see that exactly $115=70+20+25$ bought an additional item so $35$ of those $150$ customers did not buy an additional item, and so on.

Comment: @lulu, $75+21+16=112\gt110$....

Comment: @BarryCipra  Well, that's true.  Not sure how to reconcile that with the terms of the question...

Comment: The problem is bs (a technical term meaning bullshit); it says each customer buys exactly one coffee, it shows us the daily sales (which do NOT show equal number of coffees bought at each shop), but then it tells us each shop is visited with equal probability. When even the problem author doesn't understand what they write, how would one expect the student to make sense of it?

Comment: So - Nelly - if this is an assignment, show the teacher these two ways in which the problem is IMPOSSIBLE: what Barry has pointed out, and what I put in my other comment. The teacher should try to solve the problem before they assign it... :-( x3 to the teacher.

Comment: This is a past exam question and I am supposed to use it as the 'solid' basis of my exam preparation. :(

Comment: What hasn't been made clear is whether the buying of one item is independent of buying another. You will have to assume that to get anywhere with this. But is it a valid assumption?

Comment: @tomi, the problem does pretty clearly say that everyone buys a coffee and no one buys more than one other item.  So the buying of items is far from independent.

Comment: Only the lecturer knows what he is talking about I guess, so it really is open to interpretation what he actually tried to say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the well deserved criticism of the problem in my Comments, let's see how one would solve it if we ignore some of the unnecessary clauses in the problem and we make it work by changing one of the inputs. Let's say only 60 customers buy cake at Cafo (to make the numbers work with the other conditions), and the problem doesn't say stupid things like "each shop is visited with equal probability." How would you solve the problem then?

First question: Probability of a customer buying only one item. You can see the number of customers, equal to the number of coffees, is 400. On the other hand, the total number of "other" items purchased is 115 (Aroma) + 120 (Bean) + 97 (Cafo) -- remember I changed "cakes" at Cafo from 75 to 60. So, 332 customers buy an additional item (we use the fact there are no overlaps - a customer either buys exactly one "other" item or none at all). Which means 68 customers don't buy anything else; 68/400 = 0.17 (sometimes written as 17%).

Second question: Probability that a customer at Aroma buys both coffee and juice. This one is really easy: 70/150 or approx. 0.467 (46.7%).

Third question: If a customer bought coffee and cake, what is the probability they shopped at Bean? Well, how many customers bought coffee and cake across all three shops? Answer: 20+18+21 = 59; 18 of them were at Bean, so the probability is 18/59 or approx. 0.305 (30.5%)

As you can see, these problems are really easy. Don't let poor teaching, bad explanations, badly written exercises make you think probabilities are difficult or complicated; they aren't. Don't be intimidated!

Comment: Thank you! You cannot immagine how relieved I am! The way everything is explained in my course is absolutely horrible yet you managed to show me how it is done in a manner of seconds, which is simply amazing!

Comment: Ugh - you are right. I fixed it now.

Comment: "Probability that a customer at Aroma buys both coffee and juice. This one is really easy: 70/150 or approx. 0.467 (46.7%)." Why did you divide 70 by 150? shouldnt you add them and then divide them over the customer count?

Comment: No... Total customers at Aroma = customers who bought coffee, that is 150. Customers who bought coffee and juice = customers who bought juice (EVERY CUSTOMER BUYS COFFEE - that's what they told us in the problem statement), so that is 70. "coffee and juice" = "juice" = 70, "total customers'" = "coffee" = 150.